# Count values of x that satisfy given condition

Tags: algorithm

Given a number P we need to find count of those values of x which satisfy this condition :

```
(x^3 - 1)%P = 0
```

Now I need to count such values of x that satisfy this equation in interval [L,R].

**My Try :** x^3 - 1 = (x−1)(x^2 + x + 1) = 0

One root is clearly x=1 , and the others must come from the quadratic, whose discriminant is

```
Δ=1−4⋅1⋅1 = −3
```

Thus, besides one, ***there are other roots if and only if −3 is a square modulo p***

But how to find these in range [A,B] ? Please help

**Example :** Let A=1 and B=100 and P be 2 then answer is 50.

Comment: shouldn't you try Mathematics part of stackexchange? This doesnt really seem programing related so far. Also square root of -3 is `i√3`

Comment: _"x^3"_ I suppose you are aware, what the [`operator^()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) actually does?

Comment: Is this an algorithmic question or a programming question? Given that you have tagged it with both 'c++' and 'algorithm', it is not clear what you are expecting. Also, there is the ambiguity regarding the operator^, as πάνταῥεῖ mentioned. If it means the regular mathematical exponent and you ask me as a programmer, the naive solution would be to try all x from A to B in a loop and count the number of successes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Here by x^3 I mean power 3 of x.And not any bitwise operation

Comment: @TheOne I think it has more to deal with programming than mathematics.As I want an algorithm to do this

Comment: @Oguk I cant do that as A,B are upto 10^18 (Here ^ symbolises power ) .P can be upto 100000

Comment: @cooktopcoder I'd just wanted you to clarify this, as you marked your question with the [tag:c++] tag.

Comment: @Patrick87 We cant loop to 10^18 as 1≤A,B≤10^18

Comment: @cooktopcoder _"Should i edit the post ?"_ Did so already ...

Comment: @Oguk I am expecting some faster way to count these values of x.It can be in form of algorithm or a code snippet.

Comment: @cooktopcoder Ok, but then it really is not a c++ question. It's pure algorithm/mathematics. Your own question sort of suggests that as it contains not a single line of code but mathematical formulas. The c++ only comes in when you already have a ready-to-implement algorithm.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖOhk.Thanx :)

Comment: @Oguk Yeah I know.Am here to find algorithm only.Implementing it is a seperate issue

Comment: I think you setup the question wrong. The above is true iff `x^3-1=nP`, where n is a whole number. This has two imaginary root, and one non-imaginary root, `cuberoot(nP+1)`. So the solution to this is the number of perfect cubes of the form `n*P+1`. I'm sure there is a clever solution for that...

Comment: @MadScienceDreams Can you please explain.Like say we have A=1,B=100 and P=31 then what should be answer according to you?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I got your point .But Now question becomes how to find perfect cubes of the form n*P+1 in a given range ?

Comment: This is a problem statement from a live contest at Codechef.com (http://www.codechef.com/TCFS15P/problems/CUBEMOD). Basically, he's cheating.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is

```
 int count = 0;
 for(int x = A;x<=B;x++){
   if((((int)(Math.pow(x,3))-1)%p) ==0){
     count++;
   }
 }
```

Comment: But I dont know c++; so I can't convert it, forgot about that sorry.*

Comment: doesnt matter, C++ flag was taken down

Comment: you ask in the programmers section, you get a programmers answer :)

Comment: @kyleengland But A,B can be 10^18.So I cant run a loop that executes 10^18 times

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ
I was wondering if your equation will always be x^3 - x cubed,

Answer (score 1):

The key here is the restriction `P ≤ 100000` (mentioned in the comments). For `i` from `0` inclusive to `P + 1` exclusive, count the number of cube roots of `1` between `0` inclusive and `i` exclusive.

```
int[] cumsum = new int[P + 1];
for (long i = 0; i < P; i++) {
    cumsum[i + 1] = cumsum[i] + (i*i*i % P == 1 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

By the properties of modulo arithmetic, this solution pattern repeats every `P` numbers. The answer thus is

```
((B + 1) / P) * cumsum[P] + cumsum[(B + 1) % P] -
    ((A / P) * cumsum[P] + cumsum[A % P]),
```

where the first line counts the number of solutions from `0` inclusive to `B` inclusive, and the second line counts the number of solutions from `0` inclusive to `A` exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

@πάντα ῥεῖ
I was wondering if your equation will always be x^3 - x cubed,
so i noticed if it is always x cubed, the equation is simply 
(B - (A-1))/p and make the answer an int to get a whole number

so i believe I answered your question. but if you want to change the power sign on demand the equation becomes more complicates
in that case just solve the pattern i.e write down many combinations of numbers that it involves
(range size) , (X^(exp)),(p)
and have them all in order underneath each other and just find the equation for the link between them all, similar to finding the equation for a number sequence.

please let me know if I have answered your question.